# Replacing all the line containing string in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to replace a variable in a Makefile in Ruby

For ex (inside the Makefile):

```
VAR = 123
```

What I'm doing is:

```
puts text.gsub("VAR = 123", "VAR_NEW = 456")
```

The problem is that I don't know the value, so I would like to use a regular expresion to replace ALL the line containing VAR =

What regular expresion can I use?
Can I use a different approach?

Comment: Just a file containing some lines, one of them is: VAR = 123

Comment: Should both `VAR = 123` and `VAR = 4711` be turned into `VAR_NEW = 456`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 q.sub /VAR = .*/, 'VAR = 456' # replace one line
```

Comment: it is not correct, it replace latest coincidence "<something>VAR = <something>",
and "SOME_VAR = ololo" will be replaced on "SOME_NEWVAR = 456"

Comment: Sure, this won't solve all problems. No doubt it will need to be customized. For example, one might add a `^` to anchor the search to the beginning of the line. But the OP needed a starting point and I *think* I answered the question that was being asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regexp like this:

```
var = 123
new = 456
text.gsub(/\b#{var}\s?= .+/, "var = #{new}")
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer, could you explain a little bit more? What /#{var.to_s}/ means?

Comment: It's interpolation, pretty much the same as `"this string has an interpolated #{variable}"}`

Comment: VAR is a variable inside a Makefile file

Comment: I'll try to be clear, I have a file containing one line like this: VAR = 123, or VAR = 0, I only know it's VAR = . I need to replace that line with VAR = 456

Comment: i think you should use "^" for setting start line, because if will be exist two variables like "ER" and "QWER", and QWER will be after ER, script replace only QWER

Comment: Yeah, I agree, but it should be `\b` or `\s`, because text indentation. Edited :).

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correct, you can do this:

```
irb(main):001:0> text = <<EOF
irb(main):002:0" VAR1 = 111
irb(main):003:0" VAR2 = 222
irb(main):004:0" EOF
=> "VAR1 = 111\nVAR2 = 222\n"
irb(main):005:0> puts text
VAR1 = 111
VAR2 = 222
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> text.gsub!(/^VAR2\s\=\s\d+/, "NEW_VAR = 555")
=> "VAR1 = 111\nNEW_VAR = 555\n"
irb(main):008:0> puts text
VAR1 = 111
NEW_VAR = 555
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

This tool will help you figure it out
http://rubular.com/

Perhaps this

```
test.gsub(/^(VAR=\s*(['"]?))\d+\2/, $1 + "456" + $2)
```

That is, if you only want to change value of variable

Edit:

```
test.gsub(/^(VAR=\s*(['"]?))\d+\2\s*$/, $1 + "456" + $2)
```

Edit 2

```
test.gsub(/^(VAR=\s*(['"]?)).*\2\s*$/, $1 + "456" + $2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, the problem is that I don't know the size of the line where VAR is, it could be VAR = 123, or VAR = 123123

Comment: in my regexp it doesn't matter how long number is.

You may also want to try second one(edited post), which is more strict

Comment: Oh, and these will only match if you assign numeric value to VAR.

Comment: How could yo do it for string values?

Comment: The simplest way would be to replace "\d+" with ".*" See edit 2